# Encryption and Decryption using AES-256

Tags: c

i have encrypted file during their creation using AES-256 algorithm in linux kernel (read_write.c) using the following sequence of functions:-

```
           crypto_alloc_cipher()
           crypto_cipher_setkey()
           crypto_cipher_encrypt_one()
           crypto_free_cipher()
```

the above sequence encrypts the file successfully, but the same sequence with decrypt function (crypto_cipher_decrypt_one()) does not decrypts the file, can anyone help me plz. thanks in advance.

Comment: What arguments are you passing to alloc-cipher?  (Main concern would be if you were putting it into something which uses an IV which might need to be set consistently and if you're not setting it it uses whatever values in memory which would be different each call)

Comment: i m passing 3 arguments to crypto_alloc_cipher, 

       1. algorithm name 
       2. u32 type and 
       3. u32 mask 
          as crypto_alloc_cipher("aes",4,32), 

i m passing these same arguments for this function in both encryption and decyrption process, is anything incorrect in this?, if yes can u plz correct it.

Answer (score 3):

I tried already and the decrypt is working as expected. Here is my code:

```
struct crypto_cipher    *tfm;
int i;
u8 pkey[32] ={0xc1,0xb2,0x33,0x34,5,6,7,8,9,0xa,0xb,0xc,0xd,0xe,0xf,0x11,
        0xc3,0xb4,0x32,0x34,5,6,7,8,9,0xa,0xb,0xc1,0xd,0xe1,0xf2,0x12};
u8 dest[32];
u8 dest2[32];
u8 src[32]= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,51,52};
 tfm = crypto_alloc_cipher("aes", 4, CRYPTO_ALG_ASYNC);
 crypto_cipher_setkey(tfm, pkey, 32);

 crypto_cipher_encrypt_one(tfm, dest, src);
 crypto_cipher_encrypt_one(tfm, &dest[16], &src[16]);

 crypto_cipher_decrypt_one(tfm, dest2, dest);
 crypto_cipher_decrypt_one(tfm, &dest2[16], &dest[16]);



 for (i=0; i<32; i++)
 {
     pr_info("%x ", dest2[i]);
 }


  crypto_free_cipher(tfm);
```

The printk result is as expected and the dest2 array just same as src array.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used these functions (and a Google search wasn't too productive), but I suspect that I know what's going on.  AES is a symmetric cipher system, meaning that you have to use the exact same key to encode and decode.  If you call the same functions to decode and just substitute the decrypt function call for the encrypt function call, then it would seem that the cipher_setkey function call is probably changing the cipher key, which means that the encrypt and decrypt keys that you are using are different.

Try calling the decrypt function immediately after the encrypt_one function, and see if you get the correct clear text back.

Comment: what u are saying about AES is correct & i know it, i m passing the same key for encryption s well s for decryption, i cross checked it many times, but still it is not decrypting the file, any other suggestion or advice is most welcome